Problem with entering numbers in an inputbox of a web element with Selenium Python
In a web autoamtion process with Selenium Python, I am trying to enter numbers like “1985225000” to an inputbox. MY problem is that such numbers, when inserted, turn out to be like” 198-522500-0”.
Can you guide me on this issue?
Additioanl information:
The surronding HTMMl code of web element is:
<input type="text" name="search.popup.customer.customerCertificationNumber" size="12" value="" onkeypress="return autoMask(this,event,'###-######-#');">

The part of the code involving in this issue is:
national_id="1985225000"
lastName_element=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='search.popup.customer.customerCertificationNumber'][@type='text']"))).send_keys(national_id)


The number can be inserted in web element in desired format manually.
The webpage log in  requires username and password and for confidentiality consideration, I can not public them to present the problem in a reproducible way.

Try to input one index at a time as the actual user would do, instead of trying to paste the whole thing. This would be much closer to the actual user scenario and check the application as if the user is inputting the number one at a time

Thank you for your feedback. If the number is pasted the at a time manually, the number would be in the desired format in the web element. (this is the approach I am used to do at the moment: I copy the number from an excel fail and paste it in the web element without any problem.)I tried this code. But the problem still exists
'''
lastName_element=WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='search.popup.customer.customerCertificationNumber'][@type='text']")))
for  txt in national_id:
lastName_element.send_keys(txt)'''


The input field is using a JavaScript function to automatically format the input as ###-######-#.
To bypass this auto-formatting, you can try using JavaScript to directly set the value of the input field instead of using send_keys.
national_id = "1985225000"

lastName_element = WebDriverWait(driver, 50).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//input[@name='search.popup.customer.customerCertificationNumber'][@type='text']"))
)
driver.execute_script("arguments.value = arguments;", lastName_element, national_id)

This approach directly sets the value of the input field, bypassing the onkeypress event that triggers the auto-masking function.

Thank you for your feedback.  I tried your approach but it writes noting in the input box (no run time error).
